# How to resize font size on window title bar on gnome?

Tags: gnome, window, window-manager, title-bar

By default window title bar on Gnome has bigger font size. How can I resize that font size on window title bar? I want it to be smaller like on KDE or MS Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Gnome 3, you can adjust titlebar fonts with `gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
Fonts > Window title font
```

or `dconf-editor`:

```
org > gnome > desktop > wm > preferences :: titlebar-font
```

or `gsettings` (in terminal):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Droid Bold 10'
```

where `Droid Bold` is the name/type of your font and `10` is the size.
This works as long as your titlebar doesn't use system fonts:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-uses-system-font false
```

Comment: is there any gui application to do this configuration?

Comment: Yes, answer updated.

Comment: dconf-editor is unreliable in Ubuntu. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/d-conf/+bug/1024168

Comment: Does this work on 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

You could just open

1. **dconf-editor** by typing that in terminal
2. go to: **org > gnome > desktop > interface**
3. change the titlebar font.

Comment: `dconf-editor` can reset a property to default value (if you forgot it like me)

Comment: there is no 'titlebar font' there

Comment: `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/titlebar-font`
`/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/titlebar-uses-system-font`